# Chebyshev's inequality for sum of dependent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be a sequence of square integrable RV's with mean $\mu$ and covariance:
$$
\textrm{Cov}(X_i,X_j) =
\begin{cases}
\sigma^2 & \text{for } i = j \\
\rho     & \text{for } |i - j| = 1 \\
0        & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
For some $\rho > 0$.
We want to show that for any $a$>0
$$
\mathbb{P}(\mu - a < \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n} < \mu + a) > 1 - \frac{\sigma^2 + 2\rho}{na^2}
$$
I get that
$$
\mathbb{P}(\mu - a < \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n} < \mu + a) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(|\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n} - \mu| \geq a)
$$
to use Chebyschev to get that this must be greater than or equal to:
$$
1 - \frac{\textrm{Var}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)}{a^2} = 1 - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \textrm{Var}(X_i) + 2\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} \textrm{Cov}(X_i,X_j)}{a^2n^2}
$$
The first sum of the numerator evaluates nicely to $n \sigma^2$ but the second sum I get that it comes to $2(n-1)\rho$ (where I have included the factor of 2). I was half expecting this to come to $2n \rho$ instead in which case we would just divide by $n$ throughout the fraction, but then I forgot about the strict inequality. Can I just conclude that
$$
1 - \frac{n\sigma^2 + 2(n-1)\rho}{n^2a^2} > 1 - \frac{n\sigma^2 + 2n \rho}{n^2a^2} = 1 - \frac{\sigma^2 + 2\rho}{n^2a}
$$

Comment: Yes everything is correct